# How do I modify html code inside a website opened with selenium (python3)?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python script that opens a website with selenium .
After opening I want selenium to change some lines in html of some button in the website.

This is the actual code when I inspect the page with chrome dev tools

```
<button type="button" class="achieve-btn">Sometext &amp; Sometext</button>
```

this is what I want to modify code with it

```
<button type="button" class="getExamButtonId1" onclick="openInstructionsPage(6012,'getExamButtonId1','incompleteExamId10001861')">Sometext &amp; Sometext</button>
```

is it possible or not?

And if this is possible please provide the exact line of code to write in my script to do the following.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try and modify the `innerHTML` property for this element.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.achieve-btn")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'your_html_code_here'", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with JS intervention :

Also I am assuming, that this css `button[class='achieve-btn']` is unique in DOM.

```
element =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='achieve-btn']");
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'getExamButtonId1')", element);
```

similarly I would suggest to pass `onclick` attribute